# Export Excel rows with color and other details

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, export-to-excel

I have an Excel file that has a special format. Some cells have color and each color comes with a special purpose. Now I want to know how can I export a line from this Excel file to a datagridview with these colors...

[image: excel file view]

With the following code I can read the cells, but just strings, and not colors...

```
 string str;
 int rCnt = 0;
 int cCnt = 0;
 Workbook xlWorkBook;
 Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
 Range range;
 object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
 xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("myFile.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
 xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(23);
 range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

 for (rCnt=1;rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
   {
       for(cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
          {
               str = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Range).Value2 + "";
               MessageBox.Show(str);
          }
   }
```

It's not important where the Excel line would be exported (datagridview, textbox!, etc.), it should just work. :) How do I get the cell colors in my export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...

I can get the cell colors of the Excel file by the following code:

```
int colorNumber = System.Convert.ToInt32((range.Cells[cCnt, rCnt] as Range).Interior.Color);
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorNumber);
```

and then put this color in a cell of a data grid view:

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.BackColor =color; (cell[0] of row[0] for example
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = (range.Cells[cCnt, rCnt] as Range).Value2;
```